# Why am I getting "undefined" after I otherwise get the output I was aiming to get with nested for loops in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, undefined

This function's out put should just be the largest number in each array. Something in the code is adding `undefined` to the end of my output.

Is `biggest` being output one more time then the loops run through the arrays?
What is my error and how do I correct it?

Function:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var biggest = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] > biggest) {
        biggest = arr[i][j];
      }

    }
    console.log(biggest);
  }

}
```

Test:

```
console.log(largestOfFour([
[4, 5, 1, 3],
[13, 27, 18, 26],
[32, 35, 37, 39],
[1000, 1001, 857, 1]
  ]));
```

Expected Ouput:

```
5
27
39
1001
```

Actual Output:

```
5
27
39
1001
undefined
```

What is causing the `undefined` output?
When I put `arr.length-1` or `arr[i].length-1` it eliminated the last loop, but not `undefined`.

Edit:

I added an array to push my returned values into. This allowed me to get rid of `console.log` in my code. I was confused by not being able to use `return` without stopping my loops, so I defaulted to `console.log` without really understanding the consequences.

Here is my new code:

```
    function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var biggest = 0;
  var answerArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] > biggest) {
        biggest = arr[i][j];
      }
    }
    answerArray.push(biggest);
  }
  return answerArray;
}
```

Comment: The function has no return value, hence it returns `undefined` to the last console.log

Comment: You're calling `console.log` for `largestOfFour()` which has no return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function should return the result, and using `Math.max` seems a lot easier

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    return arr.map( x => Math.max.apply(Math, x) );
}

console.log(largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]));
```

Comment: This is much more succinct than what I was doing. I hadn't seen Math.max before. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're using `console.log` when you call the function as well as in the loop. Check the code below:

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var biggest = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] > biggest) {
        biggest = arr[i][j];
      }

    }
    console.log(biggest);
  }

}

//console.log(
largestOfFour([
[4, 5, 1, 3],
[13, 27, 18, 26],
[32, 35, 37, 39],
[1000, 1001, 857, 1]
  ])
  //);
```

Comment: I added an array to push my values into to get rid of console.log in the function and that worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and a [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
function largestOfFour(array) {
    return array.map(v => Math.max(...v));
}

console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is nothing returned in your function call, console log can't find anything to print.

An updated version using return

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var big_arr = [];
  var biggest = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] > biggest) {
        biggest = arr[i][j];
      }
      if(i === arr.length - 1 && j === arr[i].length - 1){
         big_arr.push(biggest);
         return big_arr;
      }
    }
    big_arr.push(biggest);
  }
}


console.log(largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]));
```